# How to run a Julia project?

Tags: julia, toml

Julia is not in my wheelhouse yet, but I have been handed a Julia project to run the code within.
This consists of a directory containing a `main.jl`, a `Project.toml` and a `Manifest.toml`.

I've read up a little on what the TOML files are for; to summarise my current understanding, they form a project or environment (not sure which, or what the real difference is).

I have installed Julia v1.3.1 at the command line by downloading the tar, decompressing and placing in my path. Typing `julia` at the command line opens the Julia CLI REPL as expected.

I have tried to run the code by using `julia main.jl`, this results in complaints about the required  packages not being present, e.g.:

```
julia main.jl
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package JSON not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("JSON")` to install the JSON package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:887
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1105
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [5] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:287
 [6] _start() at ./client.jl:460
in expression starting at /home/<user>/myproject/main.jl:3
```

I can follow the instructions here and load the required packages, but surely I shouldn't do this manually for every package? 
As every package required is listed in the `Project.toml` I guess there should be some way to tell Julia to make sure the packages in the project are made available (I'm thinking something along the lines of Python's requirements file).

I have tried `julia --project=main.jl`, but this just results in the REPL loading again with nothing happening (not sure if any project or environment is loaded or not).

How can I tell Julia to run the script in this project while taking note of the requirements and other information in the TOML files?

**Update:**
Have figured out to enter `]` at the REPL to enter the `pkg` package manager. Then I can:

```
(v1.3) pkg> activate .
Activating environment at `~/myproject/Project.toml`

(myproject) pkg> instantiate

(myproject) pkg>
```

Then leave the manager by pressing backspace.
Still not sure how to "run" everything though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You’re very close to the solution! If the files are all in a directory `dir` then the command would be

```
julia --project=dir main.jl
```

You could also start an interactive session in that environment and then run the code in the file via

```
julia --project=dir

julia> include(“main.jl”)
```

Edit: If the directory is the current working directory, then you can just use `--project=.`

Comment: Turns out the script wasn't set up to run immediately.  _After_ `include`ing as in this answer, I needed to call the function I wanted to run, e.g. `julia> main("some string", SomeConstant)`.

Comment: `$ julia --project=. ./src/main.jl
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Pluto [c3e4b0f8-55cb-11ea-2926-15256bba5781] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run 'Pkg.instantiate()' to install all recorded dependencies.`

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Package JSON not found in current path` imply that you don't have JSON installed.

You can check this by starting Julia and type `using JSON`

To install JSON all you have to do is writing `import Pkg; Pkg.add("JSON")`

See this output for example:

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.5.2 (2020-09-23)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using JSON
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package JSON not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("JSON")` to install the JSON package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:893

julia> import Pkg; Pkg.add("JSON")
   Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
   Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
  Resolving package versions...
Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
  [682c06a0] + JSON v0.21.1
Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`
  [682c06a0] + JSON v0.21.1
  [69de0a69] + Parsers v1.1.0
  [ade2ca70] + Dates
  [a63ad114] + Mmap
  [de0858da] + Printf
  [4ec0a83e] + Unicode

julia> using JSON
[ Info: Precompiling JSON [682c06a0-de6a-54ab-a142-c8b1cf79cde6]

julia>
```